# unable to pass data to a customized login view in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, authentication

```
I've changed the default login view to a customized blade view. everything is working perfectly except that it's unable to pass variables to the customized login view.the variable am passing is at the footer.i've added the variable in the authenticatedsessioncontroller but its unable to pass the data.i haven't understood the reason why yet I have defined the variable..

here is the authenticated session controller 

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Models\Events_Model;

class AuthenticatedSessionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the login view.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $events=Events_Model::latest()->take(4)->get();
        
        return view('auth.login',compact('events'));
    }
```

the $events variable is in the footer of the main layout view and its the one am trying to pass through.

Comment: which error are you getting, and show the code where you try to call the variable in the blade file

Comment: The error am getting is undefined variable: events...although I have defined the $events variable on the login controller

Answer (score 0):

Variables will only be available into mentioned blade view `auth.login` it will not be availble into main layout. You can pass variable using `@section('title', $pageTitle)` and access them in main layout with `@yield('title')`

Comment: @S N Sharma the variable is in the footer of the layout blade file...it's working in all other pages except the login Page...I was thinking the issue is the authenticated session controller, but can't figure out why it's isn't executing

Comment: Have you extended the main layout blade in login blade file?

Comment: Yes I have extended it